# Trouble using SUMPRODUCT with both AND and OR logic together

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have a table like the following:

[image]

I'm trying to count all of the rows that meet a certain criteria:

If *a DEC* is less than *c DEC* AND *a APR* is greater than *c APR* OR if *a DEC* is less than *d DEC* AND *a APR* is greater than *d APR* then count those rows.

This is the formula that I'm currently using, but it is incorrect:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G4:G6<K4:K6)*(H4:H6>L4:L6)+(G4:G6<M4:M6)*(H4:H6>N4:N6))
```

That formula will give a sum of 4 for that example table, when what I am looking for is a sum of 3.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Here's a picture of the table with more info:

[image]

Comment: It would help to know which columns your data sample sits in. Is the first column G??

Comment: @teylyn that's correct, I just added another screenshot with more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the duplicate counting by checking how many returned values are greater than zero, then use that against the data in G (or any other column)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((((G4:G6<K4:K6)*(H4:H6>L4:L6)+(G4:G6<M4:M6)*(H4:H6>N4:N6))>0)*G4:G6)
```

Using the Evaluate Formula tool, you can step through the formula and see where you need adjustments.

Comment: This solved my answer and the evaluate tool was definitely the missing step. An article I was reading said that using double minus was the main way to convert boolean arrays to 1's and 0's. Is there a reason you went with `*G4:G6)` over `=SUMPRODUCT(--(((G4:G7<K4:K7)*(H4:H7>L4:L7)+(G4:G7<M4:M7)*(H4:H7>N4:N7))>0))`? And would the formula work any differently using double minus over your solution?

Comment: Both the double unary `--` and the operators will convert a TRUE/FALSE into a 1 or 0, so you can use either. Since you already went for the operators (because the OR logic can only be done with a `+` operator), I just carried on with that. I'm a big fan of keeping formulas maintainable and using what you already understand will mean you may remember what that does when you return to the formula in a few months.